# Filling blank cells in a query result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a crosstab query:

```
    TRANSFORM Sum([NetDonation]) AS [TotalDonation] SELECT [Period] FROM [qryDonations] GROUP BY [Period] PIVOT [Category];
```

This returns:

[image]

I would like to fill the blank cells with `£0.00` maintaing the `currency` format.
I was wondering if this is possible. The base query  i.e `qryDonations` is:

```
SELECT DonarArea, DonationDate, Category, NetDonation, Allocation, IIf(Year(DateAdd('m',-7,[DonationDate]))=Year(Date()),"Current Year",IIf(Year(DateAdd('m',-7,[DonationDate]))=Year(Date())-1,"Previous Year","Other Years")) AS Period
FROM tblDonations;
```

Which returns:

[image]

If this is not possible how would you go about it? Perhaps a JOIN?

Comment: Use Nz() function like Nz(NetDonation,0)

Comment: @Harun24HR `Nz(Sum([NetDonation]),0)` does not maintain the `currency` formatting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use Nz() and Format(). However, the result is left aligned text.
`Format(Nz(Sum([NetDonation]),0) "Currency")`

So try:
`CCur(Nz(Sum([NetDonation]),0))`

Or

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([NetDonation]) Is Null, 0, Sum([NetDonation)) AS [TotalDonation] 
SELECT [Period] 
FROM [qryDonations] 
GROUP BY [Period] 
PIVOT [Category];
```

Then in query design, select [TotalDonation] calculated field and set Format property to Currency.

Comment: Thanks @June7, I have also tried `CCur (Nz(Sum([NetDonation]),0)` which seems to work but I am now thinking of changing it to `Format(Nz(Sum([NetDonation]),0) "Currency")`. I did not think that would be possible with `cosstab` query. Thanks